# Individual addresses/links to single google map w/ all addresses/links?

Tags: google-maps

Here's a page with a list of addresses:

http://www.cabq.gov/seniors/centers/seniorcenters

Is there any webapp/plugin/mashup/etc that can "read" these addresses 
and create a single Google map (or something) that shows all of them, 
so I can find the one most convenient to me?

If not, how about something like:

http://www.cabq.gov/parks/park-use-rental/parks-with-restrooms

where there are actual individual links to Google maps, but not to a 
single google map w/ all entries?

This doesn't seem hard to do, so I'm guessing someone has done it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables) - Gather, visualize, and share data tables online

Comment: Ummm, this answer seems a little overgeneralized.